# AWS Lambda 502 after deploy dev

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

This is my first time with serverless aka AWS `lambda`. 
Here is my directory tree 1st and 2nd level

```
$ tree -L 2
.
├── README.md
├── Visualization_Sarit
│   ├── BA_Read0DDataPlot1DGraph.py
│   ├── CC_ReadNew2DDataPlotLineGraph.py
│   ├── ModulesInterfaceTASK.py
│   ├── Visualization.docx
│   ├── Visualization.xlsx
│   └── inHT6Ms302
├── apps
│   ├── advanced_cases
│   ├── commons
│   ├── control_params
│   ├── device_params
│   ├── heating_params
│   ├── plasma_params
│   ├── plasma_species
│   ├── results
│   ├── scenarios
│   └── transport_params
├── experiments.py
├── f1
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   └── src
├── ht6m
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── api_urls.py
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── db_routers.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── media
├── requirements.in
├── requirements.txt
├── static
├── static_files
├── templates
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── hello.html
└── zappa_settings.json
```

Here is my settings

`settings.py`

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_celery_results',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'django_rq',
    'django_filters',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'apps.advanced_cases',
    'apps.commons',
    'apps.control_params',
    'apps.device_params',
    'apps.heating_params',
    'apps.plasma_params',
    'apps.plasma_species',
    'apps.results',
    'apps.scenarios',
    'apps.transport_params',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

`zappa_settings.json`

```
{
    "dev": {
        "django_settings": "ht6m.settings",
        "profile_name": "aegon",
        "project_name": "ht6minterface",
        "runtime": "python3.7",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-20j5uvs5p",
        "aws_region": "ap-southeast-1"
    }
}
```

Deployment went smooth and suddenly raises `502`

```sh
$ zappa deploy dev
Calling deploy for stage dev..
Creating ht6minterface-dev-ZappaLambdaExecutionRole IAM Role..
Creating zappa-permissions policy on ht6minterface-dev-ZappaLambdaExecutionRole IAM Role.
Downloading and installing dependencies..
 - psycopg2-binary==2.8.2: Downloading
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2.94M/2.94M [00:01<00:00, 1.95MB/s]
 - greenlet==0.4.15: Downloading
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 42.4K/42.4K [00:00<00:00, 492KB/s]
 - gevent==1.4.0: Downloading
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 5.44M/5.44M [00:01<00:00, 5.01MB/s]
 - cffi==1.12.3: Downloading
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 431K/431K [00:00<00:00, 1.48MB/s]
 - sqlite==python3: Using precompiled lambda package
'python3.7'
Packaging project as zip.
Uploading ht6minterface-dev-1559645572.zip (42.2MiB)..
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 44.2M/44.2M [00:22<00:00, 1.96MB/s]
Scheduling..
Scheduled ht6minterface-dev-zappa-keep-warm-handler.keep_warm_callback with expression rate(4 minutes)!
Uploading ht6minterface-dev-template-1559645689.json (1.6KiB)..
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1.65K/1.65K [00:00<00:00, 17.7KB/s]
Waiting for stack ht6minterface-dev to create (this can take a bit)..
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 4/4 [00:16<00:00,  5.44s/res]
Deploying API Gateway..
Error: Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 502 response code.
```

I don't see any error in the `zappa tail`

```sh
$ zappa tail
Calling tail for stage dev..
[1559645713491] Instancing..
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlockededdule
[1559645730278] [DEBUG] 2019-06-04T10:55:30.278Z 466c2217-3fd7-4a2e-b97c-732866c5df54 Zappa Event: {'time': '2019-06-04T10:54:50Z', 'detail-type': 'Scheduled Event', 'source': 'aws.events', 'account': '530403937392', 'region': 'ap-southeast-1', 'detail': {}, 'version': '0', 'resources': ['arn:aws:events:ap-southeast-1:530403937392:rule/ht6minterface-dev-zappa-keep-warm-handler.keep_warm_callback'], 'id': 'c2ccca98-e69a-2f19-c398-4d123d24956c', 'kwargs': {}}
[1559645730279] [DEBUG] 2019-06-04T10:55:30.279Z 466c2217-3fd7-4a2e-b97c-732866c5df54 Zappa Event: {}
[1559645731280]
[1559645970227] [DEBUG] 2019-06-04T10:59:30.227Z ad604f41-5692-47b0-8e49-894f52afc56f Zappa Event: {'time': '2019-06-04T10:58:50Z', 'detail-type': 'Scheduled Event', 'source': 'aws.events', 'account': '530403937392', 'region': 'ap-southeast-1', 'detail': {}, 'version': '0', 'resources': ['arn:aws:events:ap-southeast-1:530403937392:rule/ht6minterface-dev-zappa-keep-warm-handler.keep_warm_callback'], 'id': '166fb665-ec39-526e-6ccb-47f1d8f083d3', 'kwargs': {}}
[1559645970227] [DEBUG] 2019-06-04T10:59:30.227Z ad604f41-5692-47b0-8e49-894f52afc56f Zappa Event: {}
[1559645971229]
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Please, add your `INSTALLED_APPS` from settings.py

Comment: I am assuming that the `app` is a folder with other folders in it. All the folders have an `__init__.py` file inside?

Comment: I have updated my question. It does not has `__init__.py` in the `apps`. Give me a second. I will try it.

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: Is it working locally?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the apps according to [jonvaughan](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1210)
[Another reference](https://andytwoods.com/python-zappa-django-cookiecutter-via-pycharm.html)

Here is my working directory structure

```sh
$ tree -L 2
.
├── README.md
├── Visualization_Sarit
│   ├── BA_Read0DDataPlot1DGraph.py
│   ├── CC_ReadNew2DDataPlotLineGraph.py
│   ├── ModulesInterfaceTASK.py
│   ├── Visualization.docx
│   ├── Visualization.xlsx
│   └── inHT6Ms302
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── api_urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── celery_ht6m.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── db_routers.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
├── api_urls.py
├── apps
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── advanced_cases
│   ├── commons
│   ├── control_params
│   ├── device_params
│   ├── heating_params
│   ├── plasma_params
│   ├── plasma_species
│   ├── results
│   ├── scenarios
│   └── transport_params
├── celery_ht6m.py
├── db_routers.py
├── experiments.py
├── f1
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   └── src
├── manage.py
├── media
├── requirements.in
├── requirements.txt
├── settings.py
├── static
├── static_files
├── templates
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── hello.html
├── urls.py
├── wsgi.py
└── zappa_settings.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting 502 because once deployed with API gateway, API gateway requires a very specific response from the Lambda, otherwise it will throw you a `Malformed Lambda proxy response` aka 502.

As [mentioned in the documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/), you should make sure your Lambda is returning a response in the following structure (this must be a JSON):

```
{
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "body": "..."
}
```